# .NET : How to call CreateProcessAsUser() with STARTUPINFOEX from C#

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

Most sample code on the web for calling CreateProcessAsUser() has a similar PInvoke signature to the following:

```
    public static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(IntPtr hToken,
        string lpApplicationName,
        string lpCommandLine,
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
        bool bInheritHandles,
        int creationFlags,
        IntPtr environment,
        string currentDirectory,
        ref STARTUPINFO startupInfo,
        out PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo);
```

The problem is, I want to pass STARTUPINFOEX instead, which is allowed in Vista/W7. If I was writing C/C++ then I could just cast it.

How should I deal with this in C#? STARTUPINFOEX looks like this:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct STARTUPINFOEX
    {
        public STARTUPINFO StartupInfo;
        public IntPtr lpAttributeList;
    };
```

Should I be passing an IntPtr to the structure instead? If I change the Pinvoke signature and do something like this...

```
   IntPtr pStartupInfoEx = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(startupInfoEx));
   Marshal.StructureToPtr(startupInfoEx, pStartupInfoEx, true);
```

.. I crash my shell when I execute the CreateProcessAsUser()   :(

Any ideas gratefully received. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should just pass it like the STARTUPINFO, I mean with the `ref` keyword. The marshaling of the structure is done the same way it is done for the STARTUPINFO.

Comment: So do you mean declare CreateProcessAsUser with ref STARTUPINFOEX instead of ref STARTUPINFO?

Comment: OK, that doesn't crash BUT the call doesn't work - returning error 183. Even if I forget about setting the lpAttributeList and using it essentially as STARTUPINFO (i.e. lpAttributeList) the call returns 183. Argh.

Comment: FIXED it at last - when I declare STARTUPINFOEX I was failing to set the cb member of the embedded STARTUPINO to the value returned by Marshal.SizeOf(<a startupinfoex object>). All works now and I can reparent my processes under W7 from managed code :) Thanks for the hint about ref STARTUPINFOEX - that is exactly right.