# How to call CreateProcess() with STARTUPINFOEX from C# and re-parent the child

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, createprocess, reparenting

I need to create a new process but so that it is a "child" of another process not the current process eg re-parent the new process.

The following have got me almost there [.NET : How to call CreateProcessAsUser() with STARTUPINFOEX from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432646/net-how-to-call-createprocessasuser-with-startupinfoex-from-c-sharp) and [.NET : How to PInvoke UpdateProcThreadAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427196/net-how-to-pinvoke-updateprocthreadattribute) and http://winprogger.com/launching-a-non-child-process/

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class ProcessCreator
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool CreateProcess(
        string lpApplicationName, string lpCommandLine, ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, bool bInheritHandles, uint dwCreationFlags,
        IntPtr lpEnvironment, string lpCurrentDirectory, [In] ref STARTUPINFOEX lpStartupInfo,
        out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UpdateProcThreadAttribute(
        out IntPtr lpAttributeList, uint dwFlags, IntPtr Attribute, IntPtr lpValue,
        IntPtr cbSize, IntPtr lpPreviousValue, IntPtr lpReturnSize);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(
        out IntPtr lpAttributeList, int dwAttributeCount, int dwFlags, ref IntPtr lpSize);

    public static bool CreateProcess(int parentProcessId)
    {
        const uint EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT = 0x00080000;
        const int PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS = 0x00020000;

        var pInfo = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        var sInfoEx = new STARTUPINFOEX();
        sInfoEx.StartupInfo = new STARTUPINFO();

        if (parentProcessId > 0)
        {
            var lpSize = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr dummyPtr;
            var success = InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(out dummyPtr, 1, 0, ref lpSize);
            if (success || lpSize == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return false;
            }

            sInfoEx.lpAttributeList = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(lpSize);
            if (sInfoEx.lpAttributeList == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return false;
            }

            success = InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(out sInfoEx.lpAttributeList, 1, 0, ref lpSize);
            if (!success)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var parentHandle = Process.GetProcessById(parentProcessId).Handle;
            success = UpdateProcThreadAttribute(
                out sInfoEx.lpAttributeList,
                0,
                (IntPtr)PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS,
                parentHandle,
                (IntPtr)IntPtr.Size,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                IntPtr.Zero);
            if (!success)
            {
                return false;
            }

            sInfoEx.StartupInfo.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(sInfoEx);
        }


        var pSec = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        var tSec = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        pSec.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(pSec);
        tSec.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(tSec);
        var lpApplicationName = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "notepad.exe");
        return CreateProcess(lpApplicationName, null, ref pSec, ref tSec, false, EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref sInfoEx, out pInfo);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    struct STARTUPINFOEX
    {
        public STARTUPINFO StartupInfo;
        public IntPtr lpAttributeList;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    struct STARTUPINFO
    {
        public Int32 cb;
        public string lpReserved;
        public string lpDesktop;
        public string lpTitle;
        public Int32 dwX;
        public Int32 dwY;
        public Int32 dwXSize;
        public Int32 dwYSize;
        public Int32 dwXCountChars;
        public Int32 dwYCountChars;
        public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
        public Int32 dwFlags;
        public Int16 wShowWindow;
        public Int16 cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public int dwProcessId;
        public int dwThreadId;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public int nLength;
        public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
        public int bInheritHandle;
    }
}
```

ProcessCreator.CreateProcess(0) starts Notepad as a child of current process which is the default behaviour. So far so good.

If the value passed in is non 0 the code attempts to start Notepad as a child of the process whose process ID matches the input value (I am assuming that process exists for now).

Unfortunately that part does not work and throws the following exception:

FatalExecutionEngineError was detected
Message: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x69a2c7ad, on thread 0x1de0. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: Mabye http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427196/net-how-to-pinvoke-updateprocthreadattribute has some helpful info

Comment: But, I wouldn't expect the system to allow re-parenting of a process; that seems like a *huge* security issue.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I have found the question you link helpful but only to the point I am at the moment. This article http://winprogger.com/launching-a-non-child-process/ seems to indicate that what I want to achieve should be possible. I've probably mistranslated something to C# from that article, I just can't seem to figure out what.

Answer (score 9):

There are two issues with your code. First, the `lpAttributeList` parameter of the `InitializeProcThreadAttributeList` and `UpdateProcThreadAttribute` functions must be typed as `IntPtr` with no `out` modifier. Second, the `lpValue` parameter of the `UpdateProcThreadAttribute` function must be a *pointer* to the attribute value (in your case, `parentHandle`), not the value itself. Below is the fixed code.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class ProcessCreator
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool CreateProcess(
        string lpApplicationName, string lpCommandLine, ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, bool bInheritHandles, uint dwCreationFlags,
        IntPtr lpEnvironment, string lpCurrentDirectory, [In] ref STARTUPINFOEX lpStartupInfo,
        out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UpdateProcThreadAttribute(
        IntPtr lpAttributeList, uint dwFlags, IntPtr Attribute, IntPtr lpValue,
        IntPtr cbSize, IntPtr lpPreviousValue, IntPtr lpReturnSize);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(
        IntPtr lpAttributeList, int dwAttributeCount, int dwFlags, ref IntPtr lpSize);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool DeleteProcThreadAttributeList(IntPtr lpAttributeList);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    public static bool CreateProcess(int parentProcessId)
    {
        const uint EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT = 0x00080000;
        const int PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS = 0x00020000;

        var pInfo = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        var sInfoEx = new STARTUPINFOEX();
        sInfoEx.StartupInfo.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(sInfoEx);
        IntPtr lpValue = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            if (parentProcessId > 0)
            {
                var lpSize = IntPtr.Zero;
                var success = InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(IntPtr.Zero, 1, 0, ref lpSize);
                if (success || lpSize == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                sInfoEx.lpAttributeList = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(lpSize);
                success = InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(sInfoEx.lpAttributeList, 1, 0, ref lpSize);
                if (!success)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                var parentHandle = Process.GetProcessById(parentProcessId).Handle;
                // This value should persist until the attribute list is destroyed using the DeleteProcThreadAttributeList function
                lpValue = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(IntPtr.Size);
                Marshal.WriteIntPtr(lpValue, parentHandle);

                success = UpdateProcThreadAttribute(
                    sInfoEx.lpAttributeList,
                    0,
                    (IntPtr)PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS,
                    lpValue,
                    (IntPtr)IntPtr.Size,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    IntPtr.Zero);
                if (!success)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            var pSec = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
            var tSec = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
            pSec.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(pSec);
            tSec.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(tSec);
            var lpApplicationName = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "notepad.exe");
            return CreateProcess(lpApplicationName, null, ref pSec, ref tSec, false, EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref sInfoEx, out pInfo);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Free the attribute list
            if (sInfoEx.lpAttributeList != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                DeleteProcThreadAttributeList(sInfoEx.lpAttributeList);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(sInfoEx.lpAttributeList);
            }
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(lpValue);

            // Close process and thread handles
            if (pInfo.hProcess != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                CloseHandle(pInfo.hProcess);
            }
            if (pInfo.hThread != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                CloseHandle(pInfo.hThread);
            }
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    struct STARTUPINFOEX
    {
        public STARTUPINFO StartupInfo;
        public IntPtr lpAttributeList;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    struct STARTUPINFO
    {
        public Int32 cb;
        public string lpReserved;
        public string lpDesktop;
        public string lpTitle;
        public Int32 dwX;
        public Int32 dwY;
        public Int32 dwXSize;
        public Int32 dwYSize;
        public Int32 dwXCountChars;
        public Int32 dwYCountChars;
        public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
        public Int32 dwFlags;
        public Int16 wShowWindow;
        public Int16 cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public int dwProcessId;
        public int dwThreadId;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public int nLength;
        public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
        public int bInheritHandle;
    }
}
```