# C# - Command window appears a tenth of a second before disappear

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to hide command window when process starts. I launch McAfee virus scan using this ProcessStartInfo config:

```
ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
procInfo.FileName = args[0];
...
procInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
procInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
procInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo = procInfo;
```

Then, I try:

```
process.Start();
process.CloseMainWindow();
```

And also:

```
process.Start();
while (process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
   process.Refresh();
}
var handle = process.MainWindowHandle;
ShowWindow(handle, 0) //ShowWindow from user32.dll
```

But in both cases command window appears and before it is displayed completely, it desappears (just like maximize window and immediately minimize it). I have also played with all possible ProcessStartInfo properties combinations. I need no window is displayed in any moment. How could I achieve that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: schedule your EXE in Task Scheduler

Comment: set CreateNoWindow = false; to be true?

Comment: @techspider, this is part of bigger process, I cannot schedule it :(

Comment: @BugFinder, behavior is the same with CreateNoWindow set to false or true.

Comment: if you start it minimized do you only then breifly see an icon in the taskbar? Im guessing its coded to always show its just making the best of a bad job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Code Blocks as shown in your question, the behavior is normal.

**Let's have a look at them...**

```
//[...]
procInfo.CreateNoWindow = false; //That's not what you meant
procInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.Start(); //Will show up the console window
process.CloseMainWindow(); //Will close the main window (probably also the whole application)
```

Between [`process.Start();`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`process.CloseMainWindow();`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a short time frame, where the application is visible.

Like described by @BugFinder, it should be enough to edit the `CreateNoWindow` Value from `false` to `true`.
Check if that works.

**Your second try is getting you further away:**

```
process.Start();
while (process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
   process.Refresh(); //Let's do this as long as there is no window...
}
var handle = process.MainWindowHandle; //This occurs, when there is *already* a window.
ShowWindow(handle, 0) //ShowWindow from user32.dll
```

The idea of using Shell Functions is basically not bad, but this code is doing the same like the code above (and is also unmanaged).

Let's try a different way and take the **C# Sample from [PInvoke.Net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.createprocess)**: (not more managed than ShowWindow()...)

```
public static void StartupNotepad()
{
     const uint NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x0020;
     const uint STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = 0x1;     //IMPORTANT for you
     bool retValue;
     string Application = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir") + @"\Notepad.exe";
     string CommandLine = @" c:\boot.ini";  //Funny
     PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
     STARTUPINFO sInfo = new STARTUPINFO();
     sInfo.wShowWindow = 0;                     //IMPORTANT for you - See http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/ShowWindowCommand.html
     sInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;      //IMPORTANT for you
     SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES pSec = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
     SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES tSec = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
     pSec.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(pSec);
     tSec.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(tSec);
     retValue = CreateProcess(Application,CommandLine,
     ref pSec,ref tSec,false,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
     IntPtr.Zero,null,ref sInfo,out pInfo);

     Console.WriteLine("Process ID (PID): " + pInfo.dwProcessId);
     Console.WriteLine("Process Handle : " + pInfo.hProcess);
}
```

This example demonstrates the use of CreateProcess (MSDN Link at the bottom) in a very static manner.
I suggest you to write a more dynamic function and play around with it. The [`PROCESS_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure allows you to manipulate the newly created process later in your application. If your problem still persists using the CreateProcess() Call, it's to check whether the started application does some tricky stuff on itself. And last but not least whether the problem occurs not only on your computer...

Here are some more references:

- [SO: WindowStyle.Hidden vs. CreateNoWindow = True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094003/net-windowstyle-hidden-vs-createnowindow-true)
- [SO: How to call `CreateProcess()` with `STARTUPINFOEX` from C# and re-parent the child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554913/how-to-call-createprocess-with-startupinfoex-from-c-sharp-and-re-parent-the-ch)
- [SO: winapi: CreateProcess but hide the process' window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780465/winapi-createprocess-but-hide-the-process-window)
- [MSDN: `ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx)
- [MSDN: `CreateProcess()` Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [MSDN: `STARTUPINFO` Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**EDIT:**

Probably a workaround, but if your 3rd party App is designed to show a Window and tries to ignore your requests, [`STARTUPINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) also has `dwX` and `dwY`, which sets the Window's position if `dwFlags` specifies `STARTF_USEPOSITION`. Same for `dwXSize` and `dwYSize`.

If all else fails, you could give it a try and pass positions and sizes, which make the proces *appear invisible*. Cheers.

Comment: It has been more complicated to launch McAfee Scan than notepad in order to catch and redirect outputs, close processes or catch windows handlers. Thanks for the clue about `CreateProcess()`. :)

Comment: `in order to catch and redirect outputs` This is what [`PROCESS_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is referenced for.