# Access violation calling CreateProcess in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, createprocess

I am trying to write C# code that, running in an elevated process, creates a non-elevated process. The (only) answer to the SO question [How to call CreateProcess() with STARTUPINFOEX from C# and re-parent the child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554913/how-to-call-createprocess-with-startupinfoex-from-c-sharp-and-re-parent-the-ch) contains ready-to-use code. I copied this code, but instead of creating a process, it throws an AccessViolationException. The exception text *Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.* does not help to identify the culprit, however from low-level debugging I can see that the processor is trying to read from memory at a very small address like 0x00000004 which, of course, goes wrong.

The code, briefly explained, retrieves a handle of the desktop process, then calls InitializeProcThreadAttributeList and UpdateProcThreadAttribute to initialize the respective fields of a STARTUPINFOEX struct which is then passed into the CreateProcess Windows API function. CreateProcess should then create the new process as a child of the desktop process.

This function expects in its 9th parameter a pointer to either a STARTUPINFO or a STARTUPINFOEX (which contains a STATUPINFO at its begin). If it's a STARTUPINFOEX, the 6th parameter should contain the EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT flag.

When I *don't* pass the EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT flag so that CreateProcess think it's being passed just a STARTUPINFO, all works fine except that the created process is elevated (as is the calling process). However, as soon as I add this flag, the access violation occurs. For hours I have tried modifying parameter attributes etc., but the problem persists. I have the essentially same code running in C++, so I know it *can* work. What am I doing wrong?

The code below doesn't contain elaborated error checking, but it should compile and demonstrate the problem out of the box.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace RunNonElevatedCSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            StartNonElevated(@"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe", "");
        }


        public static int StartNonElevated(string strAppPath, string strCommandLine)
        {
            bool bSuccess = false;
            IntPtr hShellProcess = IntPtr.Zero;
            var pInfo = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
            var sInfoEx = new STARTUPINFOEX();
            sInfoEx.StartupInfo.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(sInfoEx);

            try
            {
                IntPtr hShellWnd = GetShellWindow();
                if (hShellWnd == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    return 0;
                }

                UInt32 pid;
                if (GetWindowThreadProcessId(hShellWnd, out pid) == 0)
                {
                    return 0;
                }

                hShellProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_PROCESS, FALSE, pid);
                if (hShellProcess == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    return 0;
                }

                IntPtr nBufferSize = IntPtr.Zero;
                InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(IntPtr.Zero, 1, 0, ref nBufferSize);
                if (nBufferSize == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    return 0;
                }

                sInfoEx.lpAttributeList = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nBufferSize);
                if (sInfoEx.lpAttributeList == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                if (!InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(sInfoEx.lpAttributeList, 1, 0, ref nBufferSize))
                {
                    return 0;
                }

                if (!UpdateProcThreadAttribute(sInfoEx.lpAttributeList, 0, (IntPtr)PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS, hShellProcess, (IntPtr)IntPtr.Size, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    return 0;
                }

                // s1 and s2 may not be required
                string s1 = "" + strAppPath + "";
                string s2 = "";

                // The next line causes an access violation unless you remove the 'EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT' flag
                if (!CreateProcess(s1, s2, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT | 0,
                                   IntPtr.Zero, null, ref sInfoEx, out pInfo))
                {
                    return 0;
                }


                bSuccess = true;
                CloseHandle(pInfo.hThread);
                CloseHandle(pInfo.hProcess);
                return pInfo.dwProcessId;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (!bSuccess)
                {
                    var lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + lastError.ToString());
                }
                if (sInfoEx.lpAttributeList != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    DeleteProcThreadAttributeList(sInfoEx.lpAttributeList);
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(sInfoEx.lpAttributeList);
                }
                if (hShellProcess != IntPtr.Zero)
                    CloseHandle(hShellProcess);
            }
        }

        [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();

        [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern UInt32 GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out UInt32 lpdwProcessId);

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(UInt32 dwDesiredAccess, int bInheritHandle, UInt32 dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)][return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(IntPtr lpAttributeList, int dwAttributeCount, int dwFlags, ref IntPtr lpSize);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool UpdateProcThreadAttribute(IntPtr lpAttributeList, uint dwFlags, IntPtr Attribute, IntPtr lpValue, IntPtr cbSize,
                                                     IntPtr lpPreviousValue, IntPtr lpReturnSize);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "CreateProcessW", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool CreateProcess(string lpApplicationName, string lpCommandLine,
                                 [In, Optional] IntPtr lpProcessAttributes, [In, Optional] IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
                                 bool bInheritHandles, uint dwCreationFlags,
                                 [In, Optional] IntPtr lpEnvironment, [In, Optional] string lpCurrentDirectory,
                                 [In] ref STARTUPINFOEX lpStartupInfo, [Out] out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern void DeleteProcThreadAttributeList(IntPtr lpAttributeList);

        public const UInt32 PROCESS_CREATE_PROCESS = 0x0080;
        public const int FALSE = 0;
        public const int PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS = 0x00020000;
        public const uint CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010;
        public const uint EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT = 0x00080000;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public int dwProcessId;
        public int dwThreadId;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct STARTUPINFOEX
    {
        public STARTUPINFO StartupInfo;
        public IntPtr lpAttributeList;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct STARTUPINFO
    {
        public Int32 cb;
        public string lpReserved;
        public string lpDesktop;
        public string lpTitle;
        public Int32 dwX;
        public Int32 dwY;
        public Int32 dwXSize;
        public Int32 dwYSize;
        public Int32 dwXCountChars;
        public Int32 dwYCountChars;
        public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
        public Int32 dwFlags;
        public Int16 wShowWindow;
        public Int16 cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }

}
```

When the access violation occurs, the program cannot continue; the "finally" block isn't executed.

Looking forward to any replies...

Hans

Comment: Where is the exception thrown?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, In the line with the "CreateProcess" call. This is the call stack:

  [Managed to Native Transition] 

> RunNonElevatedCSharp.dll!RunNonElevatedCSharp.Program.StartNonElevated(string strAppPath, string strCommandLine) Line 68 C#

  RunNonElevatedCSharp.dll!RunNonElevatedCSharp.Program.Main(string[] args) Line 12 C#

Comment: Maybe compare to the interop declaration found [here](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.createprocess). I have a feeling it's the `string` declarations in your support structures that can't be passed this way.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, thanks, but it makes no change. I rather suspect the "attribute list" which is the only difference between STARTUPINFO and STARTUPINFOEX, but I'm doing things exactly as in the reply which I quoted in my post...

Comment: No reason to invent your own P/Invoke declarations. Just use [C#/Win32](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32).

Comment: @IInspectable, this is an excellent point. I followed your advice and spent 2 hours adapting almost every single line of code. Result: The access violation is still here :-(

Comment: for understand reason need look for binary code

Comment: What hapens if you add `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]` on all the strings `public string lpReserved;` etc

Comment: @Charlieface, I added the attribute to all string members of structs, and to all string function parameters, unfortunately the access violation remains :(

Comment: for research this need set bp on `CreateProcessW` and look what agrument is wrong, where exactly fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `UpdateProcThreadAttribute()` is wrong. The 4th parameter needs the **address** of `hShellProcess`, not the **value**. This is even stated as much in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24339722/65863) to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554913/) you linked to (the code in the other question has the same bug):

> Second, the `lpValue` parameter of the `UpdateProcThreadAttribute` function must be a *pointer* to the attribute value (in your case, `parentHandle`), not the value itself.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-updateprocthreadattribute) for `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS` says:

> The `lpValue` parameter is **a pointer to a handle** to a process to use instead of the calling process as the parent for the process being created. The process to use must have the `PROCESS_CREATE_PROCESS` access right.

You said that you copied the other answer's code, but your code does not look like the other answer's code, and certainly does not contain the fix that the other answer had provided.

In your code, change this:

```cs
if (!UpdateProcThreadAttribute(..., hShellProcess, ...))
```

To this:

```cs
IntPtr lpValue = IntPtr.Zero;
...
lpValue = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(IntPtr.Size);
Marshal.WriteIntPtr(lpValue, hShellProcess);
if (!UpdateProcThreadAttribute(..., lpValue, ...))
...
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(lpValue);
```